# How can I configure spring mvc resources tag

Tags: spring

I'm trying use spring mvc in my project,web.xml like this:

```
<servlet>    
      <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>    
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
</servlet>    

<servlet-mapping>    
    <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>    
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>
```

my project jsp file in the :project_name/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp.

my project css file in the :project_name/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/css.
what can I confiure 
`<mvc:resources mapping="/resource/**" location="/resource/"/>`
my project host in github:https://github.com/Ryanqy/blog.git

Comment: Could you explain, what does it mean "namespace resource tag"?

Comment: Are you talking about mapping static resources?  Something like `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`

Comment: yeah,I just want to say how to configure `<mvc:resources mapping="/resource/**" location="/resource/"/>` .I add this tag in my project https://github.com/Ryanqy/blog.git in Application class,but It does't work.